# ASP.NET MVC check if user belongs to [x] group

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, usergroups

Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way and should be doing everything in action filters, in which case please point me in the right direction!

I'm setting up my ASP.NET MVC application so that the one HomeController Index action delivers two different types of content, like so:

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
  return View("IndexRegistered");
else
  return View("IndexGuest");
```

This is fine but say I want to split it into three so Administrator members get their own page...

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  if( /* user is a member of administrators */)
    return View("IndexAdministrator");
  else
    return View("IndexCustomer");
}
else
  return View("IndexGuest");
```

Can someone enlighten me as to the missing piece of this puzzle?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`Roles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.roles%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the Authorize [Action Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators,Moderators")]
public ActionResult SomeAction(){

}
```

Or use the `User.IsInRole()` method:

```
if(User.IsInRole("Administrator")) { ... }
```

Comment: if(User.IsInRole("Administrator")) was exactly what I needed, thanks!
Still open to input if there is a better way to be doing this. In the first instance of using Authorize, it seems like it would be a better way to me (though I can't really way why) except as I understand it, it only offers a blanket allow/deny condition, not multiple conditions which is what I'm after.

Comment: You can add multiple roles to the Role property, I will update the code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have one or one hundred roles specified in the role property, that example still only gives you a blanket allow or deny rule, not switching based on each of the specified roles. The second example did the job.

Comment: I've got ```The name 'User' does not exist in the current context```, so I had to change my code to: ```HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("role");```

Comment: @FilipEkberg's link isn't dead just has an extra slash, fixed version: http://wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-securing-your-controller-actions

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Authentication provider which comes out-of-the-box in the default MVC project templates it's easy to add your own role support there and track it in session, so your code above would become:

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  if(Session["Role"] == "Administrator")
    return View("IndexAdministrator");
  else
    return View("IndexCustomer");
}
else
  return View("IndexGuest");
```

and then opens possibilities like:

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
  return View("Index" + Session["Role"]);
else
  return View("IndexGuest");
```